# An official responsible for land/property?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single English word, archaic or modern, which describes an official responsible for the allocation and distribution of land or property? The closest I can think of nowadays is "zoning official" but I'm looking for a single-word title if possible.

Example: "The [???] rechecked the property lines yesterday, and he affirmed that this part is my land."

Comment: You mention someone who measures property lines (e.g. a *land surveyor*), but this would almost never be the same person responsible for "allocation and distribution" of land, which is ultimately the government, or the Crown (depending on the country). Moreover, I doubt the person doing the measuring would be considered an *official* in most jurisdictions; they are most likely a worker or contractor for the applicable registry.

Comment: It is difficult to know what you are looking for. In most Anglophone countries land is bought and sold like any other commodity. In the UK there is nobody responsible for *allocation* or *distribution*. There is a government body, called the *Land Registry* which is responsible for registering all titles to land. Another group of people called *Town and Country Planners* work for local authorities. They approve plans for the use of land, building development and alterations, and ensure that all development is within the overall framework of a local master plan, and planning policy generally.

Comment: You are right, the question was poorly-worded. I'll accept "surveyor" and be more specific next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word is "[surveyor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surveyor)."

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't known about the second meaning there.